# Is there some risk in make an online dictionary without CMSs, Struts or things like that?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, content-management-system

I'm involved in a project at the institute where I study that consists in build an thematic  online dictionary. I'm thinking in make it from zero, constructing an MySQL database and using it with servlets and jsps. I'm not professional and that's my first experience with a real project, so I'm afraid that this way may, in the future, cause problems such as difficulties in maintenance, for example.  I know that there are many CMSs, but I would to use this experience to put all my theorical abilities in practical. Yes, I've time to waste. What I need to know is: the fact that I don't know things like Struts or Spring precludes that I make a functional system?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to learn new technologies and break you head for a few hours in the beginning learning and applying it, then no, not knowing spring or struts does not preclude you from creating a functional system. Maintenance is a whole new ballgame/discussion. Even the best programmers in the world cannot create a zero maintenance system. The only thing you can do is learn the system well enough (and be prepared to make the learning on going) so that you can put in the best guard rails around it and also be able to debug issues. Now, if this system that you are planning on building needs to be a professional grade system, then I would recommend hiring/getting someone who has built web applications in the past and can maintain it. That person can help carry you until you can take over. If this is a smallish project which can live with a few initial issues/downtimes (which you can work on to improve), then I say go for it.

The best way (IMO) to learn is to take a sample application, deploy it and start reading code. See if you can trace the request from the browser (I am assuming your application is a web applications) into the framework, to your controller/models and back to the view. Grab a sample spring mvc application (for e.g. http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) and see if you can make sense of it.

Comment: Well, I've already done somethings in the project, but more for testing, like the search of words registered in the database (and the mounting of the response in the respective jsp), login system for administrators and the panel with the most important functions, like the publication of a new word and the register of others admins. So, even if I have knowledge sufficient to do things like those, it's recommended that I learn how to use frameworks like Spring, right? Thanks for answer!

Comment: @vitorgreati ...yes give Spring a shot.

Comment: I will, thank you. Just a last question: will be dificult to turn my project to the Spring specifications?

Comment: @vitorgreati, depends on the complexity of the project really. If your project is a legacy application which has gone through many releases, it might be tough. But if its a small/new project, I dont think it will be a big deal converting it to spring.

Comment: Well, as I think my project match the second option, I will try to start with the basic concepts and convert it to Spring (and use other technologies) as soon as I can. Again, thanks for the support!